# How to get ESC/POS Network Printer Status

Tags: python, printing, network-programming, thermal-printer, escpos

I'm working on a POS application and using a python script to communicate with the ESC/POS printers. I'm able to successfully send ESC/POS commands to the printer on network but i'm not able to receive response, especially when trying to get status of the printer via network.

here is the [link](https://github.com/manpaz/python-escpos) of the python lib

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am also having the same problem, did you found solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

The library that you mention has no means to fetch a response from the printer. If you have a close look, then you will see, that it does only send.

Answer (score 0):

well i was able to send DLE EOT 1 to get a b'\x16' response which is 0001 0110 in binary bits bit 3 is the status of on line or offline, but you have to reverse the bit order see : [Reverse Bit Order Python? ESC/POS DLE EOT Printer status escpos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186670/reverse-bit-order-python-esc-pos-dle-eot-printer-status-escpos)